# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in your code PHP

Tags: php

```
$sSql = "INSERT INTO comments
     ( post_id,name, email, website,content)
     VALUES (".$_POST[postid]",'".$_POST[name]"', '".$_POST[email]"', '"$_POST[website]"',  '"$_POST[content]"')";
```

I am getting the following error. Can anyone help to fix this?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in your code

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks. consider using a prepared statement, which would solve your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings aren't concatenated properly, you are missing some `.` before and after some $_POST[]

Answer (score 0):

Error was in `string concatenation` missing `.` and array missing `qoutes`

```
$sSql = "INSERT INTO comments
 ( post_id,name, email, website,content)
 VALUES (".$_POST['postid'].",'".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['website']."',  '".$_POST['content']."')";
```

Use `mysql_escape_string` to avoid [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [best way to avoid sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap with two periods. `.$_POST[postid].`

Also, make sure you escapting your `$_POST` parameters as it may be subject to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST should be used as an associative array. So the keys should in quotes : $_POST['key']

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgot some dots - unexpected strings are starting in your query.

```
$sSql = "INSERT INTO comments
     ( post_id,name, email, website,content)
     VALUES (".$_POST['postid'].",'".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['website']."',  '".$_POST['content']."')";
```

Please escape userinputs before putting it into database. And take care of the arraykeys: it works without setting them into '' because php takes them as constants, can't find a defined constant of this name, and assumes that this has to be a string. Unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. You forget quotes and dotes.

```
$sSql = "INSERT INTO comments ( post_id,name, email, website,content) VALUES (".$_POST['postid'].",'".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['website']."',  '".$_POST['content']."')";
```